# Visual studio 2015 intellisense with css font awesome

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I'm working on Asp.net MVC 5 project. I added font-awesome.css and I need intellisense for fa css classes, so I could start typing

```
<em class="fa fa-
```

and see all icons, I can choose.

Comment: you can try this- https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5fd24afb-b3b2-4cec-9b03-1cfcec6123aa

Comment: Are you using a local version of font-awesome.css or one in a CDN? I tried it on my VS 2015 and it works only if I have the file stored locally.

Comment: Yes, I use locally stored file. I will try to use that glyphfriend, hope it helps, thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this
[Glyphfriend extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5fd24afb-b3b2-4cec-9b03-1cfcec6123aa)

an extension you can use in visual studio